# Joining one table two times in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, apache-hive

I am not getting any idea how to implement it in Hive. Please suggest the way.

Assume I have hive tables like this

```
Table1:
id | primary | secondary
-------------------------
 1 | A       | [B,C]
 2 | B       |  [A]
 3 | C       | [A,B]

Table2
id | primary | Heart | Liver | Kidney
-------------------------------------   
1  | A       | 1.3   | 0     | 0.9
2  | B       | 0     | 3     | 2.3
3  | C       | 0     | 9     | 4.3

Table3
id | medicine | primary 
-----------------------
1  | M1       | A
2  | M2       | A
3  | M3       | B
4  | M4       | B
5  | M1       | B
```

Now from these tables, if table1's primary (for example A) and secondary values (for ex: B) are present in table2 and if at least one tissue is present whose values are greater than zero (here kidney is there), then I have to print the following (sample output).

```
primary | direct  | secondary | indirect  | tissue_name
------------------------------------------------------
A       | M1,M2   | B         | M1,M3,M4  | kidney
B       | M1,M3,M4| A         | M1,M2     | kidney
C       | None    | B         | M1,M3,M4  | Liver, Kidney
```

Can anyone help me how to write the queries in Hive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Transformed Table2 into below format:

```
Table2
id | primary | Tissues
-------------------------------------   
1  | A       | Heart, Kidney
2  | B       | Liver, Kidney
3  | C       | Liver, Kidney
```

Transformed Table3 into below format:

```
Table3
id | primary | drug_list
-------------------------
1  | A       | M1,M2
2  | B       | M1,M3,M4
```

From Table 1, I created two tables

1. Joining Table1 with transformed Table2 and transformed Table3 on a primary column.
2. Explode Table1 on a secondary column and Joining resultant table with transformed Table2 and transformed Table3 on exploded secondary column.

Join above two tables and find the results based on common tissue values.